# How to get N files in a directory order by last modified date?

Tags: powershell, filesystems, powershell-2.0

I want to search for one or few files with latest modified date in a big directory. Trying some PowerShell code but it does not work well for me.

```
Get-ChildItem 'D:\Temp' | Sort-Object LastWriteTime
```

I know that I can use `-Recurse` to search in all directories. But how to:

- Limit just some files
- Order in descending mode
- Do not list directory

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

- Limit just some files => pipe to `Select-Object -first 10`
- Order in descending mode => pipe to `Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending`
- Do not list directory => pipe to `Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer }`

---

So to combine them together, here an example which reads all files from `D:\Temp`, sort them by `LastWriteTime` descending and select only the first 10:

```
Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse -File -Path "C:\Users" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Date -lt (Get-Date).Date } | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 10 CreationTime,FullName | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for your help. I had an error saying that -File cannot be found. Is there any alternative option ?

Comment: PS version in my computer is 2.0

Comment: Thats probably because you are using an old PowerShell version. To fix that, replace the first line with: `Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Temp' | Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer }`. I added the version tag to your question to clarify that. I also edited my answer.

Comment: The Where-Object filter could be eliminated by adding the -File parameter to Get-ChildItem.

Answer (score 22):

This works for me:

```
PS> dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime
```

Its almost the same as the bash command:

```
$ ls -ltr
```

To Filter Directories:

```
PS> dir | Sort-Object LastAccessTime | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -NotMatch "^d"
```

(Personally, I think Microsoft should merge "out-string -stream" and "sls" to make a new command called "out-grep", so that powershell works more normally for bash users without messing around with customizing your shell. Who wants to type all of that junk just to grep a command output?)

The bash command would be:

```
$ ls -ltr | egrep -v "^d"
```

Comment: I'd use `Get-ChildItem -File`, instead of `Out-String` and `Select-String -NotMatch "^d"` to select files. This addresses some of your gripe with PowerShell. PowerShell cmdlets are discreet and loosely coupled, which is a good thing. If you type lots of PowerShell you can use default aliases and/or create your own with `Set-Alias`. Your posted commands could be done with `ls -File | sort LastAccessTime`. The OP though wanted N files, which you could do with `ls -File | sort LastAccessTime | Select-Object -Last 5`. Less typing if you create an alias for `Select-Object`

Answer (score 20):

The shortest and sweetest way I can write this

```
ls | sort LastAccessTime -Descending
```

These are just aliases for this

```
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object LastAccessTime -Descending
```

Answer (score 5):

[Martin Brandl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40904876/695671) covers the reasons, so I won't repeat that, except that in newer Powershell versions you can use `Get-ChildItem -File` to list only files and not directories (folders). I don't know when it was introduced but it is in Powershell 5.1

Here are some examples of combining `Sort-Object` and `Select-Object` to limit and sort

List the 5 most recently accessed **files** (not directories) in the current directory, in descending order

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 5
```

The 5 most recently accessed files, current directory, in ascending order

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime | Select-Object -Last 5
```

List the 5 oldest accessed files, current directory, descending order

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime -Descending | Select-Object -Last 5
```

List the 5 oldest accessed files, current directory, ascending order

```
Get-ChildItem -File | Sort-Object -Property LastAccessTime | Select-Object -First 5
```

Note also that there are a few datetime file properties you could sort on. To get all of them for a file

```
Get-ChildItem | Get-Member -MemberType Property | Where-Object -Property Definition -Like "datetime*"

   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

Name              MemberType Definition                           
----              ---------- ----------                           
CreationTime      Property   datetime CreationTime {get;set;}     
CreationTimeUtc   Property   datetime CreationTimeUtc {get;set;}  
LastAccessTime    Property   datetime LastAccessTime {get;set;}   
LastAccessTimeUtc Property   datetime LastAccessTimeUtc {get;set;}
LastWriteTime     Property   datetime LastWriteTime {get;set;}    
LastWriteTimeUtc  Property   datetime LastWriteTimeUtc {get;set;}
```

Comment: and a more interactive option if N is fuzzy, instead of piping to Select-Object, pipe to more